Is there a limit to the size of a string in Python's re.search?
I am extracting data from an API call and am using this code:
if response.status_code == 200:
    ReportResponse = re.search('<return>(.+?)</return>', response.text)
    print(ReportResponse)
    FullReport = ReportResponse.group(1)

When I use this code for a small string it returns it just fine, but when I use it for a long string of returned data, as in the report that I'm receiving, the value of ReportResponse is None and of course the ReportResponse.group(1) fails. The strings (starting and ending) are in the returned data, I have confirmed that, but for some reason it's not extracting it for me. Can someone help me?
I have used this in this exact code for other API calls, and it returns the correct result string, but in this case, I get nothing in return. So, it works fine in the same calls to the same URL but with different requests and much smaller length values. The returned report is 216,287 characters in total.

Try re.findall in place of re.search

No, there is no limit to the size of an input string for re.search.
In your case, however, you should note that the . pattern matches only non-newline characters by default, and it's highly likely that the string input in your actual use case contains newline characters between <return> and </return>, resulting in no match.
To make . match a newline character, you can set the re.S/re.DOTALL flag:
ReportResponse = re.search('<return>(.+?)</return>', response.text, re.DOTALL)


Thank you so much, that worked great. I have to learn more about regex...

There is no limit the size of string in Python's re.search(). it depend on memory available of your system.
